# Python: make Rich not style a string

Tags: python, rich

I'm using rich to style the outputs in the terminal.
I **need** to style random generated text that sometimes have within itself characters that make Rich style it ("[words]", "[/]") in another way.

Basically I code rich to make a string appear green but since the presence of this characters the string appears with small random colored part.

How can I tell to rich to style a string how I want to and stop there, instead to also look for the characters inside it?

Comment: I guess you need some form of escaping. It's unclear though, so I'd suggest you provide a [mcve], along with the output it produces and the output you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can escape a string, so Rich won't style things that look like markup tags. Easiest way to do this would be to import `escape` from `rich.markup`.

```py
from rich import print
from rich.markup import escape
print(escape("this is [literal]"))
```

See the [docs on escaping console markup](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#escaping).

Comment: Thank you, it is what i'm looking for :)